# Save selected item from dropdownlist in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to save the selected item from my `dropdownlist` menu in a MSSQL table where the menu is populated from another MSSQL table. But whenever I run my project I get compilation error,

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Here are my codes,

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BoxManager", "Home"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="editor-label">
        <strong>Full Name</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "fullname", "fullname"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname)
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add" /></p>
}
```

**Model**

```
public class BoxManagement
{
    public BoxInfo Boxes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BoxInfo> BoxCollection { get; set; }
    public ClientInfo Clients { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult BoxManager()
{
     return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BoxManager(BoxManagement BoxModel)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var AddBox = BoxModel.Boxes;
                db.BoxInfoes.Add(AddBox);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("BoxPanel");
            }
            return View(BoxModel.Boxes);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I save the dropdownlist selected item in my `BoxInfo` model? Need this help badly. Tnx.

Comment: Try something like that: @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, (List<SelectListItem>)Model.Clients, "fullname", null)

Comment: Check your datasource. It's likely that you have av key and value collection. In your case "Key" might be something else.
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "Key", "clientname")

Comment: In addition to the answers below you have other errors in your code. If `ModelState` is not valid then it should be `return View(BoxModel);` and you would need to reassign the value of `BoxCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason here is that your are passing an object of type `ClientInfo` instead of the required type which is `IEnumerable<>`. You are passing the below line into your dropdown :

```
new SelectList(Model.Clients, "fullname", "fullname")
```

The `Clients` is of the type `ClientInfo` which is not `IEnumerable`. You need to change it to something which represents the `IEnumerable`type.

An example would be :

```
Model.BoxCollection
```

This is the `IEnumerable` as per your model.

**UPDATE :**

This should be your model code :

```
public class BoxManagement
{
    public BoxInfo Boxes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BoxInfo> BoxCollection { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ClientInfo> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

This should be you controller code :

```
var ClientCollection = db.ClientsInfo.Select(..conditions..).ToList();
Model.Clients = ClientCollection;
return View(Model);
```

So basically, just bind the `Clients` object with your query into `IEnumerable` and pass that model to your view. That is all that is needed.

Comment: In my model, I've used `public IEnumerable<ClientInfo> Clients { get; set; }` instead of `public ClientInfo Clients { get; set; }`. Now I get this error, `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: That is because you would need to bind the data into your `Clients` object before sending it to the view.

Comment: Tnx but please explain more.

Comment: Show the code in which you fetch the data for the `IEnumerable<ClientInfo> Clients`

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "fullname", "fullname"))` I didn't change it.

Comment: The binding code will be in your controller. Where you will be filling that `IEnumerable` with some values and then passing it to the view.

Comment: Will it be something like, `var ClientModel = new BoxManagement { Clients = db.ClientInfoes.ToList() };` ?

Comment: Yes that is it. Just tested out. +1 for all the troubles. Tnx. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong field in your `SelectList` declaration, you're use `Client`, but shouldn't it be `Boxes` as that's the list of items. The first item in that `SelectList` constructor **must be `IEnumerable`**.

If you do mean boxes, then try:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, new SelectList(Model.BoxCollection, "fullname", "fullname"))
```

Comment: Nope, I'm using the Client model which I need to populate the dropdownlist. Now, In my model, I've used `public IEnumerable<ClientInfo> Clients { get; set; }` instead of `public ClientInfo Clients { get; set; }`. Now I get this error, `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.`. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @SinOscuras Ah right, then it sounds like your collection is `null` at that point. Make sure you populate it.

Comment: But I've datas in my Client table. There is no null value there.

Comment: @SinOscuras It sounds like it's not being returned though. Can you post the code that retrieves the client data?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Boxes.clientname, new SelectList(Model.Clients, "fullname", "fullname"))` I didn't change it.

Comment: @SinOscuras Sorry, the code that actually populates `Model.Clients`

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to understand. Will it be in my Controller?

Comment: @SinOscuras That's right, the code in the controller that populates your model

Comment: I didn't change my controller also. It's same as it is in my post. Will it be something like, `var ClientModel = new BoxManagement { Clients = db.ClientInfoes.ToList() };` ?

Comment: @SinOscuras Yes it needs to be something like that. You don't populate your model in your `HttpGet` method.

Comment: Yes that is it. Just tested out. +1 for all the troubles. Tnx. :)